# Why has Sacks' "Measure-theoretic uniformity" not been more influential?

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

In the 1969 paper "Measure-theoretic uniformity in recursion theory 
and set theory," Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 142 1969 381–420, Sacks gave
a measure-theoretic approach to several results previously obtained by
forcing. For example, he showed that, when countably many random sets
of natural numbers are added to a countable model of ZFC, the result
*with probability 1* is a model of ZF+DC+all sets of reals are measurable.

This seems to me a very enlightening view of Solovay's theorem, yet
Sacks' paper is almost unknown. (It has 10 citations on MathSciNet,
compared with 98 for Solovay's.) Is there any good reason for the
relative neglect of Sacks' paper?

Comment: Is it really correct to contrast adding random reals with forcing? After all, random-real forcing simply *is* a kind of forcing, namely, forcing with the measure algebra, as opposed to the Cohen algebra. When one says with random-real forcing that a result holds "with probability one", one is really saying that every forcing extension by that forcing notion has that property. I haven't looked at that paper recently, but I am confused by your description of it, since I had understood that results of Shelah show that one needs an inaccessible cardinal to achieve the consistency of the theory. 

Comment: If you mean Theorem 4.26 in Sacks' paper, note that the existence of an extension is not the same as "all sets are Lebesgue measurable".

Comment: @Joel. It may well be that "measure-theoretic uniformity" got 
subsumed by "random real forcing," but if so I'm still puzzled
by the lack of citations of Sacks' paper. Also by the lack of 
emphasis that "ZF + DC + all sets of reals are measurable" holds
with probability 1. You're right that Sacks' proof must assume
the existence of an inaccessible; I'm not sure exactly what role
it plays.

Comment: To add on the above, Solovay proved in 1965 the consistency of an extension of the Lebesgue measure without choice, which it what Sacks refers to (reference no. 29; 30) whereas Solovay's celebrated consistency proof which requires inaccessible was published in 1970, and is a whole other body of work.

Comment: The existence of an inaccessible cardinal is used to guarantee that there is a countable ordinal $\alpha$ so that $L_{\alpha}\models ZF+V=L$. Based on this, Sacks can perform a ramified analysis for random forcing to prove the results. 

Comment: Actually the results are quite natural from recursion theory point view. Essentially the whole results were just telling some "lowness phenomenon". If we replace $ZF$ with $KP$, then all the results remain true and become totally recursion theoretic.

Comment: Liang Yu, Sacks does not mention inaccessible cardinals in his paper, except in a footnote where he points out that except the result he is going to reprove, Solovay has shown the relative consistency of ZF+DC+"All sets are Lebesgue measurable" from the consistency of ZFC+There is an inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: He does not. But he used this fact. See the first sentence in section 4 at page 397.

Comment: Yes, but he doesn't use an inaccessible cardinal. I very much doubt that the existence of such model is even close in consistency to an inaccessible.

Comment: Indeed it is not.

Comment: What Sacks proves is different. He obtains models depending on a real parameter such that (with probability 1) the model satisfies ZF+DC+there is a translation invariant extension of Lebesgue measure to all sets of reals. This is not the same as saying that all sets are measurable. The measure he obtains is not regular, of course.

Comment: I will add an element of gossip to the discussion: back in 1982 or thereabouts, when I asked a prominent set-theorist about the Sacks paper discussed in the question, the response was "everything set-theoretic there is already in Solovay's paper".

Comment: @Ali. Thanks, that's interesting. I guess that Sack's result was
quickly superseded by Solovay's; but still, the Sacks paper came 
out first.